# Linear equations system in c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have to resolve a simple linear equation system using C++. My system is some like this:

My matrix  source:

```
-10,4000000000000   0
0   -7
-10,4000000000000   -7
```

My matrix result:

```
-40,9997173375000
-6,32530306520000
-46,1581124912000
```

In matlab i use this comand to obtain the values of x and y:

```
pos_rx_est_m=(A00\b00)';
```

Whre A00 is source and b00 result, and x and y are:

```
3,90487961862179    0,848047680195238
```

How can i implement this algorithm in c++?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a simple "linear equation system" - there are three given equations for two variables. Apparently the "best fit" (according to some measure) is required. The math for this falls under the heading "Regression analysis".

Comment: Actually the question is quite simple and answerable considering that the asker seems to seek a way to reproduce a MATLAB code which only consists of 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the hardest part of this question is figuring out what to implement.

Upon finding the right doc: [doc mldivide](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) and carefully reading it, one can find the following:

> If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix
>   with m rows, then A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system
>   of equations A*x= B.

Now it should not be hard to find something that works for you, perhaps the [LLSQ library](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/llsq/llsq.html).

Comment: Do you know something about these libraries? I have to use QR_SOLVE because my case is A*x=b not Y = A*X+B. I follow the tutorial, but when i calculate my matrix result aren´t same as matlab. thanks